# What happens when 10 light years worth of space debris is near-instantly transported to a certain point; retaining their velocity?

Tags: science-based, technology, space

One day, a non-visible beam of handwavium energy 100km in diameter and 10 light years long intersects with the our solar system, presumably originating somewhere near Proxima Centauri. The beam tears a hole through the bottom section of Jupiter. All matter that is touched by this beam is transported near-instantaneously to the end of this beam, retaining all its characteristics including its speed. The beam stretches about six light years past our solar system before petering out a split second later.

Since the beam has also transported 10 light years worth of space debris as well, what happens now? Is there a blooming field of space debris and gas that explodes outwards from where the beam ends?

Comment: It looks like you're asking about a hypothetical situation rather than asking about how to build a fictional world.

Comment: Why would it explode?  What is the energy?  That much mass is much more likely to have gravity make it cohere?

Comment: I do not understand the close vote reasoning here.  While the answer is obviously different, I see the type of question as no different to examining what happens when an indestructible meteor enters Earth's atmosphere.  Yet one is on the verge of being closed and the other was answered...  Personally I would like more information (was the chunk of Jupiter the only substantial single chunk of matter?) but I see no reason to close.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 the meteor question sounds a lot easier than this one, since we know about the effects of meteorites hitting earth and all of the necessary information was given (minus the collapse of the meteorite upon hitting the ground, his question is basically about a meteor that won't shrink in size upon entering the atmosphere). This one asks about the potential effects of colossal amounts of debris and planet parts being instantaneously teleported to a single point in space, but doesn't specify the mass or volume, how much this is clustered together or what were the original speeds,.

Comment: *Instantly*  Note that the fastest you can travel is light speed, so nothing happens instantly or even near-instantly.  If you break that rule for your fictional world you can pretty much break any physics and invent what you want to happen.

Comment: VTR: Like @KerrAvon2055, I don't understand the VTC reason. Too story based? Really? As in, depending on how the story is written something *else* will happen? At worst the OP has failed to explain exactly what mass is being picked up by the beam, precisely where it begins and where it ends, and just how compressed the matter is at the end of the beam (Jeff, edit your question to answer these!).

Comment: @StephenG The [help] states, "World building includes geography, culture and creatures for the world, not to mention magic and planetary physics, in short, everything from the physics underlying your reality to the entire universe you want to build." We are not limited by today's understanding of physics on this site unless the OP says so. Period. We also tend to get caught up in judging the backstory when it's nothing more than setting the stage for the question. We shouldn't do that, either.

Comment: @ProjectApex What you just explained sounds like a good reason to help the OP improve their question - but it's a far cry from "too story based." Can you justify how this question is about plot, circumstance, or character choice (story building)? Because it sounds like it's just missing a few initial conditions (like most questions).

Comment: @JBH I have no idea why you're telling me that, all I was doing was pointing out to the OP that he either needs to clarify "near instant" or define what the pseudo physics rules are, because you can't get instant in our physics and we have nothing to go by from his post.

Comment: @StephenG, You didn't ask the OP for a clarification, you pointed out that his/her world rules aren't our world rules, and having "broken" one he/she could "break" any. I'd conclude that you don't think the question has value simply because it doesn't conform to what we understand today. The point of the [help] statement is that it's the OP's privilege to create whatever rules they want and our obligation to answer within the context of those rules. Thus, you weren't asking for a clarification, you were complaining. But, I'll delete my comments about the matter if you'll delete yours.

Comment: Ladies and Gentlemen. All the OP did was create a set of initial conditions. Please don't focus on the backstory and therefore believe the question unanswerable. Through irrelevant methods, mass in a 10ly x 100km cylinder that pierces, among other things, Jupiter, is brought to a single point at the end of the cylinder. The mass has the same force vectors as they did in their pre-question state. What happens when t > t0? My college physics classes asked questions like this all the time - they just didn't have a creative way of setting up the initial conditions.

Comment: @JBH Not planning to delete my perfectly reasonably comment just to placate your extremely pushy attitude about this question.  You've attacked every single post that didn't lather love and affection all over the post.  People are entitled to *their* opinions and you need to learn to tolerate them, not try to bully them away.

Comment: E.E "Doc" Smith, in the 1930s, wrote in his fiction that matter, moved inertialessly by any method, retains the *intrisnic velocity* that it had at the moment before movement. So the chunk of Jupiter retains the vector of orbital velocitity. At the end of the beam, it resumes that velocity. The vector is *intrinsic*, so rotating the matter won't change the vector. He used this to smash a planet between two others with opposite velocities, called it a "nut-cracker".

Comment: @JBH oh I have no idea why this is being treated as story based. As far as I see it this is more of a "what should I expect from this event" kind of question, which is completely valid unless it's lacking the necessary information to make it possible to be answered properly. In here, for example, what was in the way of the beam (gases, solid matter, both, neither) the amount of mass that's being transported to this single spot, the volume of said single spot and the speed at which the materials/gases were moving at.

Comment: I saw other questions here basing their questions in their stories, so I thought it would be best if I did that. I don't know the density of debris in space so I can't really answer the amount of debris that would be picked up by this beam, and was hoping instead for the answer to supply some information on that. The single spot that all this matter is being transported to is presumably a sphere 100 km in diameter at the end of this beam.

Comment: @StephenG so you are saying that if I stack a bunch of objects out in space and give them wildly different vectors of travel that we can't map that because they got there instantly? Or, we can't map what would happen if a gas giant was instantly removed from the solar system? Instant =/= magic and doesn't need to turn everything to magic in a catastrophic chain reaction. Look who is being unreasonable.

Comment: @ITAlex I'm saying that stuff encountering the beam at different points along the beam (in conventional physics) will do so at different times because the beam itself will take time to travel the distance involved in the question (multiple light years).  When they are encountered they'll move at at some velocity that will be not more than the speed of light, so again they don't go anywhere instantly.  My issue is that to answer the question requires some knowledge of the system of physics ("the FTL rules") the OP's universe operates under beyond the limited amount said in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'll do is find how much interstellar matter likely exists in a cylinder 100km in diameter and 10 light-years long.
$V=\pi r^2 h$ is the volume of a cylinder, so let's find our volume in uh cubic centimeters:
$\pi × (1*10^{7})^2 × 9.461*10^{18} = 2.972*10^{26}cm^3$
Now let's find its mass.
Hydrogen has a mass of about $1.674*10^{-24} g$ and helium about $6.646*10^{-24} g$
Interstellar particle density is about 1 atom per cubic centimeter, that atom being 75 percent of the time hydrogen and about 25 percent the time helium. Let's get an average mass: $1.674*10^{-24}(0.75) + 6.646*10^{-24}(0.25) = 2.917*10^{-24} g$
Our volume calculation is in cubic centimeters, and we have 1 particle per cubic centimeter, so there are about $2.972*10^{26}$ particles inside out cylinder, each with an average mass of $2.917*10^{-24} g$. Finding total mass, we multiple the number of particles by the average mass and find that the total mass is about: $8.670*10^{2} g$, or about 867 grams of stuff.
That's about a basketball and a couple of baseballs worth of mass.

So, basically nothing when compared to the stuff the beam will grab from within Jupiter.
If we assume Jupiter has an average density of $1.326 g/cm^3$, has a radius of $6.991*10^{9}cm$, and the beam passes through say 60 degrees latitude in the south:
$\cos (60) × 2 × 6.991*10^{9} = 3.496*10^{9} cm$ is the length of that part of the beam which crosses Jupiter.
That part would have a volume of roughly: $\pi × (1*10^{7})^2 × 3.496*10^{9} = 1.098*10^{24} cm^3$
With an average density of $1.326 g/cm^3$, we can find mass to be: $1.456*10^{24} g$
That's a mass comparable to the dwarf planet Ceres.

As for what it'll do when it reaches the middle of nowhere in interstellar space 6 light-years away? I imagine that--being under the crushing pressure of Jupiter's interior no longer--it'll expand rapidly and magnificently, glowing hot at first before cooling down as its volume increases and heat escapes in greater quantities into cold, dark space. I don't think the gases' relative motion from its activities in the solar system will make much of a difference at all.

Comment: Very nice.  This really makes it clear why the Bussard ramjet concept could not work - scooping up less than 1kg of matter from a 100 km wide collection zone 10 light years long is nowhere near enough fuel to be useful even if it would all fuse with perfect efficiency.

Comment: @KerrAvon2055 yeah, if only there were a few hundred thousand more atoms per cubic centimeter